# C++11 type alias of std::array with operators

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I have a *c++11 type alias*:

```
using coord = std::array<double, 3>;
```

Can I define the operator *+* for *coord*? How? I'd want to be able to do:

```
coord a, b, c;
a = {1.1, 2.0, 0};
b = {0, -1, 3.5};
c = a + b; // c = {1.1, 1.0, 3.5}
```

Comment: FWIW, there is `std::valarray` that has this functionality built in (but it does do dynamic allocation)

Comment: I suggest you to overload operator `+`. To do this you can overload it for each and every array or you can wrap `std::array` into a simple structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouln't recommend defining new operators for STL type, or any types that aren't in your control.

I would suggest instead create your own types:

```
struct coord {
    // reimplement operator[], fill, size, etc.

    friend constexpr auto operator+ (coord const& lhs, coord const& rhs) noexcept -> coord {
        // ...
    }

private:
    std::array<double, 3> _coord;
};
```

Or you could also shortcut your way around using operators and member function already defind in `std::array`:

```
struct coord : private std::array<double, 3> {
    constexpr coord(double a, double b, double c) noexcept :
        array{a, b, c} {}

    using array::operator[];
    using array::begin;
    using array::end;
    using array::fill;
    // other operators...

    friend constexpr auto operator+ (coord const& lhs, coord const& rhs) noexcept -> coord {
        // ...
    }
};
```

---

Note: If you want to support structured binding and offer tuple like access to your `coord` class, then you must add overloads for `get` and specialize `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element`:

```
namespace std {
    template<size_t n>
    tuple_element<n, ::coord> {
        using type = double;
    };


    tuple_size<::coord> : integral_constant<size_t, 3> {};
}

template<std::size_t n>
constexpr auto get(coord const& c) noexcept -> double const& {
    return c[n]
}

template<std::size_t n>
constexpr auto get(coord& c) noexcept -> double& {
    return c[n];
}

template<std::size_t n>
constexpr auto get(coord&& c) noexcept -> double&& {
    return std::move(c[n]);
}

template<std::size_t n>
constexpr auto get(coord const&& c) noexcept -> double const&& {
    return std::move(c[n]);
}
```

This code will allow that kind of code when you switch C++17 on:

```
auto my_coord = coord{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
auto [x, y, z] = my_coord;
```

Comment: ...and then drag along `std::tuple_size` + `std::get<N>`... and deduction guides... and all the rest. There really is no pretty solution here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof you cannot add overloads to `std::get`. It's undefined behaviour to add additional overloads to standard function. However this is true you need to add `get` and tuple size

Comment: @MaxLanghof I think public inheritance would solve that.  Not sure if it is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add why you should not add an `operator+` for `std::array`. Or, more generally, why you should only add operators (or rather, free functions) to the namespace of the type they operate on (which is forbidden in the case of `std`).

For one, you can't put the operator in namespace `A` and then properly use it in namespace `B` (without `using namespace A;`):

```
namespace A
{
    using coord = std::array<double, 3>; // Putting this in the global namespace doesn't help.

    coord operator+(const coord& right, const coord& left)
    {
        return coord { right[0] + left[0], right[1] + left[1], right[2] + left[2] };
    }
}

auto foo()
{
    A::coord x, y;
    return x + y; // doesn't see the operator
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/XUR_NX

The only place left to put the operator is the global namespace. If that doesn't make you uncomfortable, here is a reason why it should: The name lookup rules will break your neck soon enough.

What if we want to write a template that uses your `operator+`? It should work fine, right?

```
template<class ... T>
auto add(T ... t)
{
    return (t + ...);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ox8_r5

Yep, it works! Well, **until someone adds *any* `operator+` closer to the template**:

```
namespace A
{
    struct X{};
    void operator+(X, X);

    template<class ... T>
    auto add(T ... t)
    {
        return (t + ...); // won't find the correct operator+ for T=coord
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ctcfxr

Name lookup stops at that `operator+`. Since your correct one (for `std::array`) is not in `namespace std` (where `std::array` is), it cannot be found by ADL (argument dependent lookup). At that point you are out of options.